# send push notification from asp.net for Azure

Tags: cordova, push-notification, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm developing an app using cordova for multiple devices, I wan't to send push notification from a website or webservice whenever a new data is inputed in the database how can this be done? I will develop for android, IOS and windows phone

Comment: You can use pushplugin. Documentation is here : https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin